# Remove injects from constructor - "Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation."

Tags: angular

I have read all another questions i have found here, but nothing helps me(

I have a hybrid app

```
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "4.4.6",
"@angular/upgrade": "4.4.6",
"angular": "1.5.8",
```

Everything worked fine, but suddenly I have added new component and a module

module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {KekComponent} from './kek.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    exports: [KekComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        KekComponent
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class KekModule {
}
```

component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'kek',
    template: 'div'
})
export class KekComponent {

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

And I get this error `Unexpected value 'KekComponent' declared by the module 'KekModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

No mistypes(code is copied), nothing else.
Where should i look for the solution?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on stackblitz? Everything seems fine.

Comment: what **IDE** are you using?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez webstorm. The problem reproduces on CI.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner no( It seems really fine, this example is simplified, but I have literally _copied_ existing component, removed all injects from it and got this error(

Comment: did you import `KekModule` to your main module?

Comment: From what you have shared, I cannot see anything wrong. It seems totally OK to me. So, if you can reproduce the problem on a stackblitz example, I would be able to help you.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ulwwbu)?

Comment: Can you stop and run again?

Comment: @JohnVelasquezo yes, I have imported it in main module. The problem is totally WEIRD, and I'm looking for some weird solutions)

Comment: Try rebuilding your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I've had such code

```
import {NgModule, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {KekModule} from './kek.module.ts';
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
```

and the solution was in *changing the order of them*

```
import {NgModule, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
import {KekModule} from './kek.module.ts';
```

facepalm hybrid apps